# Channel is not recieving data or giving dead block

Tags: go

I've the below code:

```golang
//main.go
package main

import (
    "edriven/events"
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Starting")
    events.Wg.Add(1)
    go events.User.Trigger("new", "Hasan")
    events.Wg.Add(1)
    go events.User.Trigger("name", []any{"Hasan", "Ali"})
    events.Wg.Add(1)
    go events.User.Trigger("new", "Ali")

    //for x := range <-events.Publish {
    //  fmt.Println(x)
    //}

    for {
        select {
        case x := <-events.Publish:
            fmt.Println(x)
        default:
            fmt.Println("waiting for data ...")
            time.Sleep((time.Duration(math.MaxInt64)))
        }
    }
}
```

And

```golang
//events/user.go
package events

import "fmt"

var User Events

func init() {
    User.register("new", func(payload ...any) {
        fmt.Println(payload[0])
        //message := make(map[string]string)
        //message["new"] = "done new"
        Publish <- "{'new':'done'}"
        Wg.Done()

    })

    User.register("name", func(payload ...any) {
        for index, person := range payload {
            fmt.Println(person, index)
        }
        //message := make(map[string]string)
        //message["name"] = "done name"
        Publish <- "{'name':'done'}" //message
        Wg.Done()
    })
}
```

And

```golang
//events/setup.go
package events

import "sync"

var Wg sync.WaitGroup
var Publish chan string

type Event struct {
    Name   string
    Action func(...any) // <-chan string // func(...any) ([]any, error)

}

type Events struct {
    handlers []Event
}

func (e *Events) register(name string, action func(...any)) {
    e.handlers = append(e.handlers, Event{
        Name:   name,
        Action: action,
    })
}

func (e *Events) Trigger(name string, payload ...any) {
    for _, event := range e.handlers {
        if event.Name == name {
            event.Action(payload)
        }
    }
}
```

The output I got is as below, that is nothing is exchanged through the channels

[image]

If I replaced the `for { select {} }` loop by the  `for x := range <-events.Publish { }` loop then I get the below error:

```bash
PS D:\Deployment\event-driven> go run edriven
Starting
[Ali]
[Hasan]
[[Hasan Ali]] 0
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive (nil chan)]:
main.main()
        D:/Deployment/event-driven/main.go:17 +0x1c5

goroutine 6 [chan send (nil chan)]:
edriven/events.init.0.func1({0xc000086010?, 0x1?, 0x1?})
        D:/Deployment/event-driven/events/user.go:12 +0x6c
edriven/events.(*Events).Trigger(0x0?, {0xe45ca0, 0x3}, {0xc000086000, 0x1, 0x1})
        D:/Deployment/event-driven/events/setup.go:34 +0x129
created by main.main
        D:/Deployment/event-driven/main.go:11 +0xb5

goroutine 7 [chan send (nil chan)]:
edriven/events.init.0.func2({0xc000180010?, 0x1?, 0x1?})
        D:/Deployment/event-driven/events/user.go:23 +0x45
edriven/events.(*Events).Trigger(0x0?, {0xe45db9, 0x4}, {0xc000180000, 0x1, 0x1})
        D:/Deployment/event-driven/events/setup.go:34 +0x129
created by main.main
        D:/Deployment/event-driven/main.go:13 +0x15d

goroutine 8 [chan send (nil chan)]:
edriven/events.init.0.func1({0xc000050260?, 0x1?, 0x1?})
        D:/Deployment/event-driven/events/user.go:12 +0x6c
edriven/events.(*Events).Trigger(0x0?, {0xe45ca0, 0x3}, {0xc000050250, 0x1, 0x1})
        D:/Deployment/event-driven/events/setup.go:34 +0x129
created by main.main
        D:/Deployment/event-driven/main.go:15 +0x1aa
exit status 2
PS D:\Deployment\event-driven>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This block of code is problematic

```
for {
    select {
    case x := <- events.Publish:
        fmt.Println(x)
    default:
        fmt.Println("waiting for data ...")
        time.Sleep((time.Duration(math.MaxInt64)))
    }
}
```

When `select` is invoked and assuming the `Publish` channel is still empty, the default case will run and block the main loop forever with the `time.Sleep` statement.  Hence, even if the `Publish` channel receives data from another go-routine, the main go-routine is still stuck on that Sleep statement.

Any time you want to combine a timed wait with a channel event, you can do this:

```
timerChannel := time.NewTimer(duration)

select {
case <-timerChannel.C:
    {
        // time out
    }
case x := <-events.Publish:
    {
        fmt.println(x)
    }
}
```

But since your intent appears to just block `main` from exiting, then it's even simpler:

```
for {
    x := <- events.Publish:  // blocks until Publish channel has data
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

But as you called out, that leads to a deadlock because after your three go-routines after exited, there's nothing left to do.

Quick fix:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Starting")
    events.Wg.Add(1)
    go events.User.Trigger("new", "Hasan")
    events.Wg.Add(1)
    go events.User.Trigger("name", []any{"Hasan", "Ali"})
    events.Wg.Add(1)
    go events.User.Trigger("new", "Ali")

    exitChannel := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        events.Wg.Wait()
        close(exitChannel)
    }()

    canExit := false
    for !canExit {
        select {
        case x := <-events.Publish:
            {
                fmt.Println(x)
            }
        case <- exitChannel:
            {
                canExit = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As discussed in the comments, channel is required to be initialized, a [make](https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#allocation_make) is missing, it has to be done as:

```golang
package events

import "sync"

var (
    Wg      sync.WaitGroup
    Publish chan string
)

func init() {
    Publish = make(chan string)
}
```

Comment: The 'for { x :<- events ....... }` gives me an error: 'All goroutines are asleep - deadlock!'

Comment: Changing the block did not change the result, still getting the same :(

Comment: Because you never started another go-routine.

Comment: Let me update my answer....

Comment: How, I started 3 goroutines, did not I?

Comment: You are correct. But as as those three go routines exited and you've printed out all the available messages in `events.Publish`, your program is officially dead-locked by blocking on the `<-events.Publish`. Because the run-time knows there's nothing that's going to wake it up.

Comment: No my friend, the printed results are something generated inside the executed functions, these not related to the channel data, no single data looks to be transfered through the channel :(

Comment: I introduced a new channel that allows your program to safely exit when all the work is done. See my updated answer.

Comment: As you have it, I'm not sure where you are creating the events.Publish channel to begin with. You've commented out most of the `make` statements.

Comment: It is in the `setup.go` file, created as `var Publish chan string`

Comment: With the modified code, I got `All goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`

Comment: You need to `make` your channel, don't you?  I don't see that happening.

Comment: mmm, how, may I did not get your point.

Comment: I just added `init func with Publish = make(chan string)` still the same

Comment: yes it worked, you can mention it in your answer, it is miss night here. Thanks Alot

Comment: It took me a while to get the hang of Channels as well.

Comment: Deeply appreciated, thanks a lot dear

Comment: Please upvote and/or accept if you found the answer useful or helpful.